# How to add a class on text when clicked to its respective image and remove it when click at another image and do the same with other image text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have six vertical dots as images and i am giving respective text to it
when clicked on the image its respective text change its property.

i tried clicking on the picture and selecting its respective text id but it should be working dynamically

```
 $(".parallx-dot-1").on('click',function(){
  $("#123").css("color","white");
```

I want when parallx-dot-1 is clicked its respective icon-text change its css property to `color:#ffffff`

**Current code**

```
$(".parallx-dot-1").on('click',function(){
  $("#123").css("color","white");
//$("$icon-text").css("color","white"); <-- (Class replaced with id)
```

```css
.icon-text {
  position: relative;
  right: 40px;
  color: #5D5D5D;
  font: 16px 'HelveticaNeue regular';
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="paralx-position">
  <li class="parallx-dot-1"><span class="icon-text" id="123">Accelerate</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div2" id="img2" tabindex="0"/>
  </li>
  <li class="parallx-dot-1"><span class="icon-text">Transform</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div3" id="img3" tabindex="0"/>
  </li>
  <li class="parallx-dot-1"><span class="icon-text-main">Build</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-2" class="Active" data-box="div1" id="img1" tabindex="0"/><span class="icon-position"><img src="images/logos/noun_build_1909132.svg" class="icon"/></span>
  </li>
  <li class="parallx-dot-1"><span class="icon-text">Ignite</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div4" id="img4" tabindex="0"/>
  </li>
  <li class="parallx-dot-1"><span class="icon-text">Develop</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div5" id="img5" tabindex="0"/>
  </li>
  <li class="parallx-dot-1"><span class="icon-text">Engineer</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div6" id="img6" tabindex="0"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `<img>` tags are self-closing - just do `<img ... >`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `text-color` from purple to white in css,Hope this helps

```js
$('.parallx-dot-1').click(function(e){
$(this).find('span').addClass('text-color')
})
```

```css
.icon-text{
position:relative;
right:40px;
color:#5D5D5D;
font:16px 'HelveticaNeue regular';
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

.text-color
{
color:purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="paralx-position">
  <li class="parallx-dot-1"><span class="icon-text" id="123">Accelerate</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div2" id="img2" tabindex="0"/>
  </li>
  <li class="parallx-dot-1"><span class="icon-text">Transform</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div3" id="img3" tabindex="0"/>
  </li>
  <li class="parallx-dot-1"><span class="icon-text-main">Build</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-2" class="Active" data-box="div1" id="img1" tabindex="0"/><span class="icon-position"><img src="images/logos/noun_build_1909132.svg" class="icon"/></span>
  </li>
  <li class="parallx-dot-1"><span class="icon-text">Ignite</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div4" id="img4" tabindex="0"/>
  </li>
  <li class="parallx-dot-1"><span class="icon-text">Develop</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div5" id="img5" tabindex="0"/>
  </li>
  <li class="parallx-dot-1"><span class="icon-text">Engineer</span><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div6" id="img6" tabindex="0"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not working 
$('.paralx-dot-1').onClick(function(){
$(this).find('span').addClass('text-color')
});

Comment: i changed it but its not working 
it is not selecting the span/icon-text property
:-(

Comment: have you included jquery cdn,is there any error in console?

Comment: post your entire code,you made syntax error in various places it seems

Comment: $('.paralx-dot-1').on('click',function(){
  console.log("HELLO");
$(this).find('span').addClass('text-color')
});

Comment: console.log is totally working its showing HELLO in console.
it is not selecting the span element having id of icon-text and not adding the class text-color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192312/discussion-between-deepak-and-inderjeet-vyas).

Answer (score 0):

You can used the below script,it will add active class to span tag respectively the image is click.

```
$(".parallx-dot-1").click(function() {
   $(this).find('span').addClass('active');
});
```

and in active class you can set color like this:

```
.active{
  color:#ffffff;
}
```

Comment: This is not working but i implemented the same thing other way using id's
but like this i cannot swap in between the text color if its there its fixed. 

$('#img2').on('click',function(){
$("#2").addClass('active');
});